# Using FreeForm 4.0.12 with Low NoSpam 2.2.3 / Akismet EE 2.6

Tags: add-on, solspace-freeform

I have installed FreeForm and Low NoSpam, built new Free Forms, signed up for Akismet, got the API key installed it, configured the settings for the products.  Yet, nothing is being blocked.  I can submit dozens of messages without any checking.  Put in crappy information.  Everything that spam catching should get.   Yet, every entry just nicely goes through to my Freeforms submissions.   It just appears to bypass everything.   I use a separate machine to test from, so I am not logged in.  It seems like Akismet is not in the loop.

Akismet seems odd to me.   My former Akismet account gave me a control panel.  The new Akismet just gives me the API key.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Snaptcha (http://www.putyourlightson.net/snaptcha)

Comment: I am having a similar issue with Low NoSpam 2.2.3 and EE 2.5.5.
All the spam comments go to pending but there is no way check them as spam as in the Low NoSpam screenshot (http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nospam), the only solution is to delete them.

Comment: Make sure the accessory is enabled for the Comments page in the CP. The 'mark as spam' checkbox should appear when you select 'Delete Selected' from the drop down.